# LED Status And Display Issue

Tags: android, service, notifications, led

```
    NotificationManager notifMgr = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE); 
    Notification notif = new Notification();
  //Use this if you want to use the default lights for a notification
    notif.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS;

    //Use this if you want custom values for the LED
    notif.ledARGB = 0xff0000ff;          // Blue flash
    notif.ledOnMS = 300;                 // LED's on for 300 ms
    notif.ledOffMS = 1000;               // LEDs off for 1 second
    notif.flags |= Notification.FLAG_SHOW_LIGHTS;

    notifMgr.notify(1234, notif);
```

I am using this code to change the color of my phone led. But I am unable to see the change. Where I am wrong?
Second thing is there anyway to get the status of LED or not.
I am testing our HTC Hero/Htc G2. On Bat Low and Email and SMS my cell phone gives me a blinking led and glowing trackball. so i think my system has the support. 
Why this code is not working don't know can anyone tell me?

Answer (score 1):

This line ignores your led customization:

```
notif.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS;
```

Remove this line.

Answer (score 0):

> Where I am wrong?

Quoting the Android documentation for `ledARGB`:

> The hardware will do its best approximation.

What this really means is, you get what the device manufacturer wants you to get. Not all manufacturers give the same support to LEDs for use with `Notification`.

> On Bat Low and Email and SMS my cell phone gives me a blinking led and glowing trackball. so i think my system has the support. Why this code is not working don't know can anyone tell me?

HTC is welcome to use its own LEDs for its own purposes. Just because HTC uses LEDs one way for its own firmware applications does not mean that third party developers like us get the same results.

As a result, while you are welcome to try flashing an LED, you should not be counting on it working. Many devices do not even *have* an LED.